# How to skip a line with more values more/less than 6 in a .txt file when importing using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file with 170k rows. I am importing the txt file into pandas.

Each row has a number of values separated by a comma.
I want to extract the rows with 9 values.

[image: The data file snippet]

I am currently using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('uart.txt', sep=",")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should try - preprocess the file.

```
import csv
with open('uart.txt', 'r') as inp, open('uart_processed.txt', 'w') as outp:
    inp_csv = csv.reader(inp)
    outp_csv = csv.writer(outp)
    for row in inp_csv:
        if len(row) == 9:
            outp_csv.writerow(row)
```

There can be more efficient way to do that, but it the simplest thing you can do and it entirely removes invalid rows.

As @ksooklall answered, if you need only 2 columns for simplicity:

- [a,b,c,d] will be in your DataFrame as [a, b]
- [e] as [e, Nan]

So, if you're ok with that - go ahead and no preprocessing required.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of the 9 columns, you can do:

`df = pd.read_csv('uart.txt', names='abcdefghj')`

This will only read the first 9 columns.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your header rows are fine,

you can use `data = pd.read_csv('uart.txt', sep=",", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)`

This will ignore any lines having more than the desired amount of values and will also show which such lines were skipped.

If you know the rest of the actual data (i.e. lines that have 9 values) don't have any missing values in them, then you can `dropna` after reading it in to drop all rows that have less than 9 records. i.e. (`data = pd.read_csv('uart.txt', sep=",", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True).dropna()`

However, if the records that have 9 values can have NAs (e.g. 242,2421,,,,,,,1) then I don't think there's a built-in way in Pandas and you'd have to pre-process the csv before reading it in.